# Vb. Net mysql odbc

Tags: mysql, vb.net, odbc

I am writing a vb.net project with mysql and while coding I face some error and  could not find the solution the error I have set my phone number datatype size to 20 but in vb. Net I can enter 10 digits nunber when i tried to enter this error shoes I have attached the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omkle.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please read why not upload images of code and/or errors on SO when asking a question [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is you've declared the column as INT(20) thinking that means it's an int that can store 20 digits; it doesn't

And then youre trying to put a number like 4,123,456,789 (10 digits) into it not realizing that the max value of an integer is 2.1 ish billion

Use a string to store your number, and also read http://bobby-tables.com; never again should you write an SQL like you have there. [It's dangerous](https://coar.risc.anl.gov/consequences-of-sql-injection-attacks/) and I know employers that have fired developers for less

Comment: Thank you so much you really help my problem i used sting as you say now my error is fixed thank you so much again

Comment: @Shen the best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.